# How to kill subprocess of xdg?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I spent a lot of time searching for the answer for my question, but I could not find it.

1. I run **xdm-open**, using subrocess, to **play a video** (*I do not want to know what applications are available*)
2. I'm waiting for a while
3. I want to **kill the video**

```
import os
import subprocess
import psutil
from time import sleep;
from signal import SIGTERM

file = "test.mkv"
out = subprocess.Popen(['xdg-open', file])
pid = out.pid

print('sleeping...')
sleep(20.0)
print('end of sleep...')

os.kill(pid, SIGTERM) #alternatively: out.terminate()
```

Unfortunatelly the last line is killing only the **xdg-open** process. The mplayer process (which was started by xdg) is still running.

I tried to get the sub-processes of the xdg by using the following code:

```
main_process = psutil.Process(pid)
children_processes = main_process.children(recursive=True)
for child in children_processes:
    print("child process: ", child.pid, child.name())
```

but it did not help either. The list was empty.

Has anybody an idea how to kill the player process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programs like `xdg-open` typically look for a suitable program to open a file with, start that program with the file as argument and then exit.

By the time you get around to checking for child processes, `xdg-open` has probably already exited.

What happens then is OS dependant. In what follows, I'll be talking about UNIX-like operating systems.

The processes launched by `xdg-open` will usually get PID 1 as their parent process id (PPID) after `xdg-open` exits, so it will be practically impossible to find out for certain who started them by looking at the PPID.

*But*, there will probably be a relatively small number of processes running under your user-ID with PPID 1, so if you list those *before* and *after* calling `xdg-open` and  remove all the programs that were in the before-list from the after-list, the program you seek will be in the after-list. Unless your machine is very busy, chances are that there will be only one item in the after-list; the one started by xdg-open.

**Edit 1:**

You commented:

> I want to make the app OS independent.

All operating systems that support xdg-open are basically UNIX-like operating systems. If you use the [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) Python module to get process information, you can run your "app" on all the systems that `psutil` supports:

- Linux
- macOS
- FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD
- Sun Solaris
- AIX

(`psutil` even works on ms-windows, but I kind of doubt you will find `xdg-open` there...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I should not use any OS specific behavior, as I want to make the app OS independent.